# Chefspec unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm no developer and a newbie with Chef.

I created a simple recipe and tested it on a test Kitchen and it works well but when I upload it to Jenkins it won't pass.

Can you help me point out what I'm missing?

```
Recipe:
# Recipe:: default
# Download VerneMQ
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb" do
  source 'https://bintray.com/artifact/download/erlio/vernemq/deb/trusty/vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb'
end

# Install
dpkg_package 'vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb' do
  source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb"
  action :install
end

# Service Start
service 'vernemq' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end

# Configurations
template '/etc/vernemq/vernemq.conf' do
  source 'vernemq.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end

template '/etc/vernemq/vmq.passwd' do
  source 'vmq.passwd.erb'
end
```

This is my unit test.

```
Unit Test:
require 'spec_helper'
require 'chefspec'

describe 'vernemq::default' do
  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04').converge(described_recipe) }

  it 'downloads the remote_file' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_remote_file('#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb')
  end

  it 'installs a dpkg_package' do
    expect(chef_run).to install_dpkg_package('vernemq')
  end

  it 'executes both actions' do
    expect(chef_run).to enable_service('vernemq')
    expect(chef_run).to start_service('vernemq')
  end

  it 'creates a file' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/etc/vernemq/vernemq.conf')
  end

  it 'creates a file' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/etc/vernemq/vmq.passwd')
  end
end
```

errors from Jenkins

01:06:57 tm_vernemq::default
01:06:58 [2018-07-19T01:06:58-07:00] WARN: Chef::Provider::AptRepository already exists!  Cannot create deprecation class for LWRP provider apt_repository from cookbook apt
01:06:58 [2018-07-19T01:06:58-07:00] WARN: Property `sensitive` of resource `apt_repository` overwrites an existing method. Please use a different property name. This will raise an exception in Chef 13. (CHEF-11)/tmp/d20180719-10648-933ma2/cookbooks/apt/resources/repository.rb:54:in `class_from_file'.
01:06:58 Please see https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_property_name_collision.html for further details and information on how to correct this problem. at /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:43:in`call'
01:06:58 [2018-07-19T01:06:58-07:00] WARN: AptRepository already exists!  Deprecation class overwrites Custom resource apt_repository from cookbook apt

```
01:06:58   executes both actions
01:06:58   installs a dpkg_package (FAILED - 1)
01:06:58   creates a file (FAILED - 2)
01:06:58   creates a file (FAILED - 3)
01:06:58   downloads the remote_file (FAILED - 4)
01:06:58 
01:06:58 Failures:
01:06:58 
01:06:58   1) vernemq::default installs a dpkg_package
01:06:58      Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to install_dpkg_package('vernemq')
01:06:58 
01:06:58        expected "dpkg_package[vernemq]" with action :install to be in Chef run. Other dpkg_package resources:
01:06:58 
01:06:58          dpkg_package[vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb]
01:06:58         
01:06:58      # ./test/unit/recipes/default_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
01:06:58 
01:06:58   2) tm_vernemq::default creates a file
01:06:58      Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/etc/vernemq/vmq.passwd')
01:06:58 
01:06:58        expected "directory[/etc/vernemq/vmq.passwd]" with action :create to be in Chef run. Other directory resources:
01:06:58
```

Comment: Please include the full error message, not just the first line of it.

Comment: Added the jenkins error

Comment: All errors are correct. You have the name mismatch I mentioned below and are using `create_directory` for your config files (they are not directory resources).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the full error message so this is mostly a guess but you have `dpkg_package 'vernemq_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb' do` vs `install_dpkg_package('vernemq')`. Those need to have the same name in them.